# creating an even to update table columns with random numbers

Tags: mysql, events, mariadb

I am trying to create an event using mySQL (mariaDB) where every 1 hour it updates each row of a column called "itemRandomize" with random numbers. I tried several things, and I get either error syntax or required super user.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
CREATE EVENT main
DO
UPDATE main SET itemRandomize = FLOOR(RAND() * 100000000);
```

My oldschool code that did an update (but no randomization) was something like:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
CREATE EVENT itemupdater
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2013-10-26 06:36:00'
DO
UPDATE items SET shopStockCurrent=shopStockMax;
```

I am also getting an error that says #1046 - No database selected.
I haven't done this sort of stuff in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Let's address your error messages:

- "Need to be super user" -- `EVENTs` need to be created by a privileged user.
- "No database selected" -- then do `USE some_db` before `CREATE EVENT`.
- "syntax errors" -- Let's see the details.

Instead of converting to an integer, you could simply store `RAND()` in a `FLOAT` column (only 4 bytes).

What will you be doing with the random numbers?

How big is the table?  (Will the task finish in an hour?)

If the column `itemRandomize` is indexed, this *might* speed things up:

```
ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX itemRandomize;
UPDATE ... SET itemRandomize ...;
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX(itemRandomize);
```

I say "might" because there have been significant changes (speed ups) in these kinds of `ALTERs` in recent MySQL versions.  I don't know if MariaDB has caught up.

The reason why dropping and recreating the index *may* be beneficial is because of how costly the `UPDATE` is -- It must remove an entry from the index and insert a new entry in a new place.

Comment: So according to my user that I added ksdfksdkf_me as all privileges, but when I try to turn on event schedulers, it still throws a not a super user message. I am wondering if I am missing something, maybe I am not as _me or something?

Comment: Let's double check...  `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ksdfksdkf_me'@'localhost';`  Or was he not coming in from "localhost"?

Answer (score 0):

RAND() - is very slow function. Try somthing like this ( sory, iam dont check my code):

```
SET @tm = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
UPDATE main SET itemRandomize = FLOOR( SIN( @tm + `id`) * 100000000) + 100000000;
```

`+ 100000000` if you are need only positive values

You say: `I am also getting an error that says #1046 - No database selected.`

```
use [myDatabseName];
...
[your SQL-code here]
...
```

Or just define DB in SQL statement:

```
UPDATE [myDatabseName].main SET itemRandomize = FLOOR( SIN( @tm + `id`) * 100000000) +
```

Comment: Using `BENCHMARK()`, I get 30ms for a million RAND()s and 70ms for your expression.  I vote for RAND().

Comment: Hmmm... I am now getting error #1577 Cannot proceed because system tables used by Event Scheduler were found damaged at server start.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/100685/cannot-proceed-because-system-tables-used-by-event-scheduler-were-found-damaged/224487

Comment: Sory about `RAND` )